# How can I create PDF/X-3:2002 compliant PDF files from Delphi?

Tags: delphi, pdf, pdf-generation

From my Delphi application I require to create a PDF document that is PDF/X-3:2002 compliant.

This is a strict requirement of the client as the PDF files are going to be printed in a printing press.

I have wPDF but it does not support. (Please see: http://wpcubed.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5693)

If no component currently exists, then what techniques and other software can I use to accomplish this? The application allows the user to add images and rich-text onto templates (TPanels) that should make up the pages of the PDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you manage your color?

If you use RGB Colors in your Delphi application to handle the image, PDF/X-3:2002 won't be just a matter of tagging.

The [PdfLib](http://www.pdflib.com) do handle this format, and can be used in Delphi.

I guess that default PDF/A-1 settings will meet most of the PDF/X-3 requirements, especially:

- Embed fonts;
- Include color profile;
- Contain metadata.

Our [Open Source engine](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/02/08/Synopse-PDF-Engine-1.12) is able to produce PDF/A-1 files - if you take a look at the specs, you may be able to generate PDF/X-3:2002 compliant PDF files.

Comment: Thanks Arnaud, I am going to take a look at the PDFLib components now.